# Is it possible to add a database element to google tasks?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a website where the user has certain tasks. These tasks can be deleted by clicking on an image:

```
<img class="delete" id="<?php echo $tasks[$c][0]; ?>" title="delete" onclick="Delete(this)" />
```

Is it possible that the user can add a certain this task to their Google tasks the same way? I guess on button click the user is redirected to google tasks, authorization etc..

Comment: Are you talking about the API?

Comment: I've seen the API but didn't find any related tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/firstapp for some information.

Then after you have tried getting it to work (and hopefully succeeding) if you get stuck, post another question with details of what you have tried and what's not working.